# Class pointer usage

Tags: c++

Can anyone explain pointer usage of this code piece;

`b2Body* b = node;`

`GameActor* myActor = (GameActor*)b->GetUserData();`

Comment: `b` or `myActor`? You may also need to show how `b2Body` and `GameActor` are defined.

Comment: 2 line has different usage so i want to know both usage

Comment: b2Body is class and GameActor not defined, in this code used as sample

Comment: If GameActor is not defined, you can't use it.

Comment: We assume its defined, so box2d author used as it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
b2Body* b = node;
```

Declare a pointer `b` pointing to whatever `node` currently points to.

```
GameActor* myActor = (GameActor*)b->GetUserData();
```

Get some kind of pointer out of `b`, and cast it to pretend it points to an object of type `GameActor`. If the pointer really does point to that type, then `myActor` can access that object. Otherwise, all hell is about to break loose.

Comment: Where did you get the line "node = node->GetNext();" from?

Comment: @gartenriese: From the question, before it was edited.

Comment: Ok, I guess I was too late to see it.

Comment: I deleted it from code piece because not related to question. Normally middle line is > node = node->GetNext();

Answer (score 1):

```
b2Body * b = node;
```

This creates a pointer of the type b2Body with the name b. b points to the object node points to.

```
GameActor* myActor = (GameActor*)b->GetUserData();
```

This creates a pointer of the type GameActor with the name myActor. myActor points to the result of the member function of class b2Body called GetUserData().

You can split the second line into two lines to make it more clear what's happening.

```
auto * data = b->GetUserData();
GameActor * myActor = (GameActor *)data;
```